# Shell Script to do SSH followed by further commands

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh

Usually in a shell script you can write commands such as

```
command1
command2
command3
```

and they will be executed one after another.

I want to write a Unix shell script to SSH onto a server and THEN execute commands on that server.
For example

```
ssh user@server.com
ls
```

I try to do this as shown above but ls doesn't display output. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can feed in commands to ssh on the command line or on stdin. If you have just one command to execute, do:

```
ssh user@server.com ls
```

If you have multiple commands, use heredoc syntax to pass them in via stdin:

```
ssh user@server.com <<END
command1
command2
command3
END
```

Comment: The only problem is that it logs me out automatically. Is there a way so that I stay logged in?

Comment: ^^ add a line `bash` before `END` ;-)

Comment: The commands

    ssh user@server.com <<END
    command1
    command2
    command3
    bash
    END

still logs me out for some reason. It logs me out regardless of whether I run it from a shell script or type the commands into the terminal directly.

Comment: I think the issue is that the `bash` command inherits its standard input from `ssh`, which is using the here document for standard input. When the last line is read, the "file" closes, and `bash` will then exit.

Answer (score 2):

Although the other answers to my question have been fantastic, I ended up using a small modified version. Thought I'd share it with the forum for anyone who's interested.

```
ssh -t username@server.com "
command1
command2
command3
bash -l"
```

advantages: it doesn't log you out!

Many thanks to anishsane and John Kugelman

Comment: See my comment to John Kugelman's answer. Here, `bash -l` still inherits its standard input from `ssh`, but now `ssh` is using your local terminal for standard input, not a here document.

Answer (score 0):

Use Passwordless SSH as mentioned in [this guide](http://www.yourownlinux.com/2014/05/how-to-passwordless-secure-shell-ssh-login-using-ssh-keygen.html).

And then your script will contain:

```
ssh user@server.com command1
ssh user@server.com command2
ssh user@server.com command3
```